# Why findPreference(key) returns null?

Tags: java, android

When I use findPreference(key) to get specific part of preferences and add values dynamically I am getting null instead.

I have no clue what I am doing wrong. I have tried other ways of using findPreference() method. I have looked through tutorials and Q/A on Stackoverflow - all without success.

Here is my SettingsActivity code:

```java
public class SettingsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        SettingsFragment sf = new SettingsFragment();
        fm.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.content, sf)
                .commit();

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_settings);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        sf.addCustomList("pref_key_calendar", new CharSequence[]{"One", "Two", "Three"}, new CharSequence[]{ "1", "2", "3" });
    }

    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootkey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings, rootkey);
        }
        public void addCustomList(String key, CharSequence[] entries, CharSequence[] entryValues) {

            ListPreference customListPref = (ListPreference) findPreference(key);
            customListPref.setEntries(entries);
            customListPref.setEntryValues(entryValues);
        }
    }
}
```

Here is XML with peferences:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

        <PreferenceCategory
            android:title="Main"
            android:key="pref_key_settings_main">

            <ListPreference
                android:key="pref_key_calendar"
                android:title="@string/pref_key_calendar"
                android:summary="@string/pref_key_calendar_descr"
                />
            <SwitchPreference
                android:key="pref_key_review"
                android:title="@string/pref_key_review"
                android:summary="@string/pref_key_review_descr"
                />
            <Preference
                android:key="pref_key_review_time"
                android:title="@string/pref_key_review_time"
                android:summary="@string/pref_key_review_time_descr"
                />
            <ListPreference
                android:key="pref_key_read"
                android:title="@string/pref_key_read"
                android:summary="@string/pref_key_read_descr"
                android:defaultValue="2"
                android:entries="@array/pref_read_list_titles"
                android:entryValues="@array/pref_read_list_values"
                />
        </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I will have to replace `new CharSequence[]{"One", "Two", "Three"}` with list of installed calendars - this is why `sf.addCustomList` must be invoked from the SettingsActivity class.

When I enter settings screen then this error occurs (line number points at setEntries() execution in addCustomList() function):

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.package1.novamowa, PID: 22093
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package1.novamowa/com.silverdragon.kalafono.SettingsActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference.setEntries(java.lang.CharSequence[])' on a null object reference
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3194)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
                   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.support.v7.preference.ListPreference.setEntries(java.lang.CharSequence[])' on a null object reference
                      at com.silverdragon.kalafono.SettingsActivity$SettingsFragment.addCustomList(SettingsActivity.java:47)
                      at com.silverdragon.kalafono.SettingsActivity.onCreate(SettingsActivity.java:35)
                      at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7383)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1218)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3147)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3302) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(Unknown Source:0) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1891) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:108) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:166) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7425) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:245) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:921)
```

I am wondering - this project has been copied from another one and package name changed. It should not affect findPreference() execution, should it?
Please help!

Edit: I have solved the issue.

```java
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
    public static class SettingsFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {
        SettingsActivity invoker;

        @SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
        public SettingsFragment(SettingsActivity invoker) {
            super();
            this.invoker = invoker;
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootkey) {
            setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.pref_settings, rootkey);

            CalendarList cl = invoker.getListOfCalendars();
            String[] ids = cl.ids.toArray(new String[cl.ids.size()]);
            String[] names = cl.names.toArray(new String[cl.names.size()]);

            ListPreference customListPref = (ListPreference) findPreference("pref_key_calendar");
            customListPref.setEntries(names);
            customListPref.setEntryValues(ids);
        }
    }
```

adding constructor to SettingsFragments with `invoker` as a parameter allowed me to call back getListOfCalendars() function and use results to add to respective ListPreference nod in the hierarchy.

I have no clue why IDE forced me to add this @SuppressLint("ValidFragment") annotation, but program works so I don't mind :).

If somebody thinks my solution is incorrect I will be happy to hear your suggestions.

Cheers!

Comment: If you want to know what is going on, put a log to see if the preferences are loaded. I think it is not.

Comment: I don't really know how to log that, but I know that preferences ale loaded in onCreatePreferences. I have experimented with adding `if(customListPref != null)` around `setEntries()` execution - UI displayed all settings from my xml. But obviously my ListPreference is empty there.

Comment: OK! I have figured that out. Function addCustomList() from SettingsFragment was invoked before onCreatePreferences(). This was the root cause of my issue. I solved this by adding callback to SettingsActivity in SettingsFragment class. Then by using it I could run function in SettingsActivity from onCreatePreferences(). In there, after setPreferencesFromResource() I added lines for putting calendars information into respective Prerences key.

Comment: Yeah, exactly. You should have added a callback from activity to fragment, having it instantiated in onActivityCreated and then you call your method in which you can do the stuff you want.

Comment: For me it was a stupid mistake. I only added `title` to the `PreferenceCategory` not the key :-(, make sure you also add the key `android:key="pre_item_key" ` and find by the key.